# Subdivision surface leaving harsh lines on an object?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to subdivide the mesh for a cat I 3d Modeled and it is leaving harsh lines in some places. there are no creases or vertices on top of each other. I have also tried deleting and replacing all faces where the lines meet which proved ineffective. does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image] Harsh Lines along the back of the cat
[image] Harsh Lines along the front leg of the cat

Comment: Pinching like this can occur if two edges (that are meant to be on a rounded surface) are too close together. This is also (occasionally) caused by flipped normals. For the normals, try (in edit mode) `select all > mesh > normals > recalculate outside`.

Comment: maybe share your file (or a part of it) so that we can check: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/